# Invalid conversion from int to wchar_t

Tags: c++

This is my file code.

File1.cpp

```
void CIME::AddExceptKey(wchar_t key)
{
    m_exceptKey.push_back(key);
}
```

File2.cpp

```
PyObject *imeAddExceptKey(PyObject *poSelf, PyObject *poArgs)
{
    int key;
    if(!PyTuple_GetInteger(poArgs, 0, &key))
    {
        return Py_BuildException();
    }

    CPythonIME::Instance().AddExceptKey(key);
    return Py_BuildNone();
}
```

And this is my warning:

```
warning C4242: 'argument': conversion from 'int' to 'wchar_t', possible loss of data
```

And warning is on this line :

```
CPythonIME::Instance().AddExceptKey(key);
```

What I do wrong ? I tried with `wchar_t` key but no chance.

Comment: The title of the question doesn't match the error you have.

Comment: As for your problem, I'm guessing you're on a Windows system (where `wchar_t` is a 16-bit data type and `int` is a 32-bit data type)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I edited it.   Yes i compile sources with visual studio as a 32bit machine.

Comment: Then think about the warning message and what it says about "possible loss of data" in the context of converting a 32-bit type to a 16-bit type.

Comment: To give an analogy:  Can't convert an apple into an peanut.  'you' know apples can be turned into peanuts (with your fancy pea-napple machine), but the compiler doesn't unless you cast it. The compiler is warning that apples are bigger than peanuts, so you will lose some of the apple during the conversion.

Comment: @Neil ahahahhahah , good explain for a beginner. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The size of int may be 2 or 4 bytes depending on implementation and size of wchar_t also varies between 2,3 or 4 bytes of data. It is warning that there may be loss of data. You have to debug and see if there is any loss.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an int where a wchar_t is required without a cast.

```
CPythonIME::Instance().AddExceptKey((wchar_t)key);
```

However I really doubt that is what you want to do.  I don't know what these functions do, but "GetInteger" and "AddExceptKey" indicate you are getting maybe a keycode and adding a key by character.  So please RTFM before you cast, otherwise you may have unexpected behaviour.